# Taking residues with integer assumptions?

Tags: functions, assumptions

In some cases, Mathematica successfully produces a general result for residues with assumptions, such as:

```
Assuming[Element[n, Integers] && n >= 0, Residue[Gamma[x], {x, -n}]]
```

> `(-1)^-n/n!`

In other seemingly simple cases, Mathematica gets hung up on the task:

```
Assuming[Element[n, Integers] && n > 1, Residue[x^(-1 - n) Exp[x], {x, 0}]]
```

> `Residue[E^x x^(-1 - n), {x, 0}]`

Is there a way to make Mathematica return the appropriate residue for general integer `n>1` in this case without having to interfere "by hand" with some derivatives? How should this be done properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`SeriesCoefficient`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeriesCoefficient) instead:

```
Assuming[n ∈ Integers && n>1,
    Simplify @ SeriesCoefficient[
        Exp[x] x^(-1-n),
        {x, 0, -1}
    ]
]
```

> 1/n!